# Can't see certain wireless networks

Tags: wireless

I'm having issues seeing specific WiFi networks. I'm running Ubuntu 14.04.1 on a late 2010 MacBook Air. At first I thought it was the internal wireless adapter so I bought a USB one but that didn't solve the problem. I also can't see the same networks if I use the MacOS X (Mavericks) partition so I'm a bit lost as to why this could be.

I ran the wireless-info script with the USB wireless adapter attached

I'll post it in a comment because I get an error for too long a post.

**Edit**

This is the link to the log.

http://pastebin.com/jzjviHp4

Comment: Is it the internal or the USB you want to fix? I suspect they conflict and you ought to work on one at a time.

Comment: If I had to choose one, the USB adapter would be it. I first had the problem without the adapter and that's why I bought it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you blacklist and unload the driver for the internal device:

```
sudo -i
echo "blacklist wl"  >>  /etc/modprobe.d/blacklist.conf
modprobe -r wl
exit
```

Then fix the USB as described here: [NETIS WF2120 Wifi Adapter Drops Signal Within Seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551522/netis-wf2120-wifi-adapter-drops-signal-within-seconds/551648#551648)

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I still haven't been able to try it out. Will let you know how it goes when I do.

Comment: It worked great! After building the new driver wiz the instructions in the link, I removed the internal device driver from the blacklist and now both adapters can see the WiFi network.