# Wifi issuse, first time user

Tags: wireless, networking, drivers, network-manager

I finally built a PC of my own and I created a duel booting system (Windows 8 and Ubuntu). Windows 8 works flawlessly but Ubuntu is the most infuriating thing I've ever dealt with.

I can't access the internet with out it disconnecting every 10 seconds. I'm using a Rosewill USB RNX-N250UBE. Another issue is every time i start the OS is says there was issue with mounting/Windows.

```
NetworkManager Tool

State: connected (global)

- Device: wlan0  [NETGEAR-HOME1] -----------------------------------------------
  Type:              802.11 WiFi
  Driver:            rtl8192cu
  State:             connected
  Default:           yes
  HW Address:        68:1C:A2:16:0D:26

  Capabilities:
    Speed:           72 Mb/s

  Wireless Properties
    WEP Encryption:  yes
    WPA Encryption:  yes
    WPA2 Encryption: yes

  Wireless Access Points (* = current AP)
    *NETGEAR-HOME1:  Infra, 30:46:9A:4E:4C:26, Freq 2437 MHz, Rate 54 Mb/s, Strength 80 WPA WPA2

  IPv4 Settings:
    Address:         192.168.1.9
    Prefix:          24 (255.255.255.0)
    Gateway:         192.168.1.1

    DNS:             192.168.1.1


- Device: eth0 -----------------------------------------------------------------
  Type:              Wired
  Driver:            e1000e
  State:             unavailable
  Default:           no
  HW Address:        38:2C:4A:AF:E9:8E

  Capabilities:
    Carrier Detect:  yes

  Wired Properties
    Carrier:         off
```

Comment: Please see: http://askubuntu.com/questions/551522/netis-wf2120-wifi-adapter-drops-signal-within-seconds/551648#551648

Comment: Tried didn't work

Comment: What didn't work? Did you encounter errors? Did you try a reboot?

Comment: It seems to be working but I still have the "an error occurred while mounting /windows"

Comment: I suggest you start a new question with that approximately in the title. Glad the wireless is working.