# installing a wireless USB adapter in Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: wireless, software-installation, adapter

I have a Edimax ew-7811Un and I get a message saying I do not have permission to extract the zip file from the installation cd.

Comment: Most USB Wi-Fi adapters from Edimax are just supported under Ubuntu. Try plugging it right in and seeing if you are able to connect to wifi from your networking menu.

Comment: @HeatherBrown Thank you but I have already tried that.

Answer (score 1):

See [NETIS WF2120 Wifi Adapter Drops Signal Within Seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551522/netis-wf2120-wifi-adapter-drops-signal-within-seconds/551648#551648) but instead of command `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9` use `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10` per instructions at https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes