# rtl8192cu Ubuntu Mate 15.10 issues

Tags: networking, drivers, 15.10, mate, realtek-wireless

I have an Edimax Wireless adapter that uses the rtl8192cu driver. I followed the instructions provided in the post: [NETIS WF2120 Wifi Adapter Drops Signal Within Seconds](https://askubuntu.com/questions/551522/netis-wf2120-wifi-adapter-drops-signal-within-seconds/551648#551648?newreg=06b398bae3694123a8c136c4ae9a8f05)

I even went as far as changing the command provided by HackerBaloo

> "This worked fine in 15.10 today, I just had to change to : sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10"

I had no way of connecting with an ethernet cable, so I downloaded all of the packages while my other adapter was plugged in. I then unplugged all of my wireless adapters before performing any of the dkms commands.

Upon rebooting; however, My adapter no longer functions at all. I had to un-blacklist the driver to get it to function, albeit the same unstable way,as before.

I had followed these instructions on a previous install of Ubuntu MATE 15.04, and it all went off without a hitch. It nearly tripled my up/download speeds and maintained a connection.

I further tried to do the same install as the post on a separate installation of 15.04, and I was unable to use the command

```
sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9
```

I recieve this output on both machines:

```
Error! Could not find module source directory.
Directory: /usr/src/8192cu-1.9 does not exist.
```

I understand this process should work I'm just not sure where it is going wrong. Any assistance would be greatly appreciated.

lsmod output:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
cfg80211              548864  0
r8712u                180224  0
nvram                  16384  0
video                  36864  0
msr                    16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
joydev                 20480  0
snd_hda_codec_realtek    86016  1
snd_hda_codec_generic    77824  1 snd_hda_codec_realtek
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     49152  1
snd_hda_intel          36864  5
snd_hda_codec         135168  4 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_intel
snd_hda_core           65536  5 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel
snd_hwdep              16384  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               106496  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_core
snd_seq_midi           16384  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
snd_rawmidi            32768  1 snd_seq_midi
kvm                   512000  0
edac_core              53248  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi_event,snd_seq_midi
edac_mce_amd           24576  0
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_seq_midi
snd_timer              32768  2 snd_pcm,snd_seq
snd                    81920  21 snd_hda_codec_realtek,snd_hwdep,snd_timer,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_pcm,snd_seq,snd_rawmidi,snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_intel,snd_seq_device
soundcore              16384  1 snd
serio_raw              16384  0
k10temp                16384  0
shpchp                 36864  0
asus_atk0110           20480  0
8250_fintek            16384  0
mac_hid                16384  0
i2c_piix4              24576  0
parport_pc             32768  0
ppdev                  20480  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                49152  3 lp,ppdev,parport_pc
autofs4                40960  2
uas                    24576  0
usb_storage            69632  2 uas
hid_generic            16384  0
usbhid                 49152  0
hid                   118784  2 hid_generic,usbhid
pata_acpi              16384  0
amdkfd                122880  1
amd_iommu_v2           20480  1 amdkfd
radeon               1519616  3
psmouse               126976  0
r8169                  81920  0
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 radeon
mii                    16384  1 r8169
ttm                    94208  1 radeon
pata_atiixp            16384  0
drm_kms_helper        126976  1 radeon
ahci                   36864  2
firewire_ohci          40960  0
drm                   356352  6 ttm,drm_kms_helper,radeon
libahci                32768  1 ahci
firewire_core          65536  1 firewire_ohci
pata_via               16384  0
crc_itu_t              16384  1 firewire_core
wmi                    20480  0
```

Comment: Try `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.10`. Apparently, the package version has changed in [dkms.conf](https://github.com/pvaret/rtl8192cu-fixes/blob/master/dkms.conf).

Comment: That is what I tried next. That left me with no functionality for the device.

Comment: Does running `sudo modprobe 8192cu` help? Can you add the output of `lsmod` to the question. It looks like the module may not be loaded.

Comment: >modprobe: FATAL: Module 8192cu not found

Comment: Well, you may want to re-do it, starting with `sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu-fixes`. The last command is also redundant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to download that directory to your home folder and add it again:

```
sudo dkms add ./<directory_name>
sudo dkms install <module_name>/<version>
```

You can find the module name and version in dkms.conf file.

You can install same driver from another source

```
git clone https://github.com/lwfinger/rtl8192cu.git
sudo dkms add ./rtl8192cu
sudo dkms install rtl8192cu/0.1
```

But you need to make sure that `rtl8192cu` is not blacklisted in `/etc/modprobe.d` by the previous driver.