# How can I fix frequent connection drops of my WiFi?

Tags: 14.04, networking, drivers, wireless

I have an [Edimax USB WiFi](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B003MTTJOY). I plugged it in and it started working. However, I still downloaded and installed the driver following [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509498/is-there-a-standard-wifi-driver-for-the-edimax-ew-7811un).

Still, my WiFi connection is frequently dropped. It's not that my router connection at my home is bad because my phone WiFi works perfectly and never drops. Other laptops work fine as well.

How can I fix this problem in Ubuntu? Any of you previously had this problem? If you can give any pointers, that would be helpful.

Executing the following command again connects to the WiFi fine:

```
sudo service network-manager restart
```

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04. My Wireless card details:

> Edimax Technology Co., Ltd EW-7811Un 802.11n Wireless Adapter [Realtek
>   RTL8188CUS]