# Cannot install wireless drivers 16.04 EW-7811DAC

Tags: networking, drivers, 16.04, wireless

I have [Edimax EW-7811DAC](http://www.edimax.com/edimax/merchandise/merchandise_detail/data/edimax/global/wireless_adapters_ac600_dual-band/ew-7811dac/) working on windows, but on Ubuntu there are no wireless connections showing.

`iwconfig` shows

```
lo        no wireless extensions.
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
```

I followed some ideas from [this](https://askubuntu.com/questions/509498/is-there-a-standard-wifi-driver-for-the-edimax-ew-7811un) thread but I get errors.

If I try to install the driver from Edimax - `./install.sh` I get this error:

```
scripts/Makefile.build:258: recipe for target '/EW-7811DAC_Linux_Driver_4.3.19/driver/rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.19.5_17672.20160506_BTCOEX20150921-58/core/rtw_cmd.o' failed
make[2]: *** [/EW-7811DAC_Linux_Driver_4.3.19/driver/rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.19.5_17672.20160506_BTCOEX20150921-58/core/rtw_cmd.o] Error 1
Makefile:1403: recipe for target '_module_/EW-7811DAC_Linux_Driver_4.3.19/driver/rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.19.5_17672.20160506_BTCOEX20150921-58' failed
make[1]: *** [_module_/EW-7811DAC_Linux_Driver_4.3.19/driver/rtl8821AU_linux_v4.3.19.5_17672.20160506_BTCOEX20150921-58] Error 2
make[1]: Leaving directory '/usr/src/linux-headers-4.4.0-31-generic'
Makefile:1622: recipe for target 'modules' failed
make: *** [modules] Error 2
##################################################
Compile make driver error: 2
Please check error Mesg
##################################################
```

Trying the rt8192cu fails due to my ubuntu being a newer version. Now I can't retry it because I get this error:

```
You cannot add the same module/version combo more than once.
```

Trying Wild Man's solution I get to `sudo dkms install 8192cu/1.9` and get this error:

```
Directory: /usr/src/8192cu-1.9 does not exist.
```

Is there something else I should be doing?

Comment: The Edimax driver only covers kernels up to 4.1. You need to find a newer driver that's compatible with your kernel. You might look at https://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux

Comment: That worked for me, thanks.  Do you want to make it an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Edimax driver only covers kernels up to 4.1. You need to find a newer driver that's compatible with your kernel. You might look at http://github.com/abperiasamy/rtl8812AU_8821AU_linux